# How to clean several Python versions from /usr/lib?

Tags: python, linux

How do I "clean" my python on Linux Ubuntu? What I see in my `/usr/lib/` is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.11
/usr/lib/python3.8
```

I'd like to keep the minimum needed to run basic Ubuntu system.